# Trigger Automatic Id

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to create a trigger that each time that a new record is added, its create a automatic identifier, but no using sequences.

```
CREATE TABLE EPS(EPSID, EPSDesc);
```

The one who has to be atomatic is the EPSID, so i tried like this but didnt work:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER t_EPS
BEFORE INSERT ON EPS
FOR EACH ROW
INSERT MEDICAMENTOPACIENTEDIASEMANA
    VALUES EPSID= dbms_random.value(1,100) number from dual;
```

So what can i do to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to assign a value to one of the columns of the record which is to be inserted, you just write:

```
:new.epsid := dbms_random.value(1,100);
```

So it would look like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER t_EPS
BEFORE INSERT ON EPS
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  :new.epsid := dbms_random.value(1,100);
  -- (the rest of the trigger here)
END;
```

**Edit** I see you have another table in your trigger, is the trigger supposed to insert a record to another table? If so, use:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER t_EPS
BEFORE INSERT ON EPS
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO MEDICAMENTOPACIENTEDIASEMANA (epsid)
    VALUES (dbms_random.value(1,100));
END;
```

Comment: I wrote wrong the name of table is only one, like the first answer you gave, thanks a lot!.